# R Shiny removeUI is not working on selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have shiny selectInput with choices and a button. so when I click on the button shiny input has to be remove. But it is removing don't know why it is!. I have used shiny removeUI like below:

```
library(shiny)

  # Define UI
  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("rmv", "Remove UI"),
    selectInput(
      inputId=paste("FilterOperator",1,sep = "_"),
      label = "",
      choices=sort(unique(c("Begins with","Equals to","Not Equals to","Contains","Not Contains"))),
      multiple=F,
      selectize = F

    )
  )

  # Server logic
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$rmv, {
      removeUI(
        selector = paste("#FilterOperator",1,sep="_"),
        multiple = TRUE,
        immediate = TRUE,
        session
      )
      print(input$FilterOperator_1) #It prints always a value instead of null
    })
  }

  # Complete app with UI and server components
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is it removeUI wont work on selectInput? please help me anyone on this.

**Added:**

When I am trying to get value after the removing using above code, still it is returning value instead of null.

[image]

Comment: The selector should be `#FilterOperator_1`.

Comment: I have trying to remove dynamic selectinput, though I have taken your answer, it is not returning NULL,

Comment: can reproduce that adding # successfully removes the ui (its jquery syntax,...). What exactly is your open issue?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is removing but when I am trying to get value it should return NULL, but it returning previous selected value.

Comment: and with `immediate=FALSE` ?

Comment: if I mention as FALSE, it is returning NULL but not immediately , only on  Next time trigger .

Comment: That's because you put `print(input$FilterOperator_1)` on the same observer, I think.